# Cannot implicitly convert type in Linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I have below simple query,

```
Expression<Func<Info, bool>> Check = x=> true;
var result = from ab in context.Infos where Check select ab;
```

But I get this error
Cannot implicitly convert type

Can anyone explain this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```cs
var result = from ab in context.Infos.Where(Check)
   select ab;
```

Compiler expects "right" part of the expression lambda in the method syntax `where` so it generates actual expression (i.e. from `from ab in context.Infos where true` it will generate corresponding expression `ab => true`, for example [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWDkQHQBkBLAOwEdMYSAXAbQF1FiBXAWwCMBTAJwGdEBeRAG9EAVgA0iCPEkAOSQGZJANkkQwAXwpYICgDzUAfI1YBFJtwCeEAbET3EAMy4B7FifckPnXrgCCPOZWAIZsADYcABQAlHYOAO4AFtwciFRcFnH2LlwAJtxslh5ZiDwcEQDGVB4UQA)).

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't give more details about the issue that i am facing, trying to implement a specification pattern with linq syntax. I have inherited a  multi joined linq query. from ab in context.Infos where excludeFromDateLowerThanBusinessDate.SpecExpression select ab, this give me the above error. SpecExpression is  public override Expression<Func<AbTran, bool>> SpecExpression
        {
            get { return ab => ab.FromDate.Value.Date <= _businessDate; }
        }

Comment: @Jyothish the issue is the same. You can't use `Expression<Func<..., bool>>` here.